# ExtJs ViewModel Bind Field doesn't work on array

Tags: arrays, extjs, bind, viewmodel, extjs5

I'm trying to bind (two ways bind) some field of my form with data provided by my view model.
When I bind a simple string, it works perfectly. But when I try to bind a form field to an array field inside my viewmodel, modifications are not considered by the view model.

This is my model

```
Ext.define('Front.model.User', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [{
        name : 'id',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'email',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'last_connection',
        type : 'date',
        dateFormat : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    }, {
        name : 'birth',
        type : 'date',
        dateFormat : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    }, {
        name : 'schedule',
        type : 'auto'
    }]
});
```

This is my ViewModel

```
Ext.define('Front.view.user.SheetModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias : 'viewmodel.sheet',
    requires : ['Front.model.User'],
    data : {
        currentUser:null
    },
    model : 'Front.model.User'
});
```

This is my Form

```
Ext.define('Front.view.user.Sheet', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    requires : ['Front.view.user.SheetController'],
    controller : 'sheet',
    viewModel : {
        type : 'sheet'
    },
    config : {
        currentUser : null
    }, {
        xtype : 'textfield',
        fieldLabel : 'De',
        name : 'morningstarttest',
        width : 60,
        bind : {
            value : '{currentUser.schedule.lundi.am.start}'
        }
    }
});
```

The bind displays the correct value the first time but doesn't update if I change the value.

The 'schedule' field in a model is an array.

Any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How can your code know which item in the array to bind against? You'd need to do something like:

```
{currentUser.schedule[0].lundi.am.start}
```

In order to specify an array index. I can't remember offhand if you can do this, and that's because this just feels like a bad idea. I'd suggest rethinking what you're attempting to do. Rather than have schedule as a field on your model, look into associations.

Comment: I'm not currently on this project for now. I'll try it as soon as I will work on it again.

However, thank you for your answer. It just make me think in other way.